# How create a settings menu with checkbox Android

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-checkbox, preferencescreen

I want to create a preference screen in which there are three checkboxes; the first one is clickable and the other two are not until the first is checked.

How can I do this? I've seen [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/), but there is only one checkbox. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <PreferenceCategory
           android:summary="@string/summary_category"
           android:title="@string/title_category">
           <CheckBoxPreference
                 android:key="main"
                 android:defaultValue="true"
                 android:summary="@string/summary_main"
                 android:title="@string/title_main" 
          />
          <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="firstDependent"
                android:summary="@string/summary_firstDependent"
                android:title="@string/title_firstDependent"
                android:dependancy="main"
          />
          <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="secondDependent"
                android:summary="@string/summary_secondDependent"
                android:title="@string/title_secondDependent"
                android:dependancy="main"
          />
    </PreferenceCategory>
<!--Any other categories include here-->
</PreferenceScreen>
```

You can do this simply by setting `android:dependancy` to the key of the check box in which the respective check boxes must depend on.

Now create a folder named xml in res folder and put your preferences xml file inside that. 
Then do the following.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


    }


}
```

You can also do this with fragments which is more recommended. But the above method is much more easy. If you want to do that with fragments, check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) which contains everything you need to know about creating a Settings Activity.

> **Hope this helps.**

Comment: Thanks. Have i to set something in the java?

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it like in that example, but you'll have three `checkboxes` instead of one. If you want two `checkboxes` to be disabled until the first one is true you can use the `android:dependency` property. With this property you need to specify the **key** of the preference they will depend on.

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:summary="..."
    android:title="..." >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="first"
        android:summary="@string/summary_first"
        android:title="@string/title_first" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:dependency="first"
        android:key="second"
        android:summary="@string/summary_second"
        android:title="@string/title_second" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:dependency="first"
        android:key="third"
        android:summary="@string/summary_third"
        android:title="@string/title_third" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```